# ActiveRecord ignores configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => 'mysql2',
  :database => 'vft',
  :user => 'vft',
  :password => 'vft_password'
)

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Attachment.all
```

This code throws `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql::Error)` with both mysql and mysql2 gems. The `vft` user is real and works with vft database through phpmyadmin or console. Here is my environment:

Debian Squeeze,
Rails 3.2,
RVM Ruby 1.9.3

Same code works good on my local PC(Ubuntu), the problem occurs only on remote VDS...

Comment: If you're using Rails, what is in your database.yml? Rails might override the ActiveRecord connection with that. I am just guessing though.

Comment: I've tried this outside Rails environment without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should replace :user with :username.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can u explain why does my code works on local PC and doesn't on other?

Comment: It is probably due to different privileges settings on MySQL. As AR could not find the username options, it falled back to root as the user.

Glad it works now.